# Insert multiple images in using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a excel report with multiple images using `VB.Net` (not macro).

I can use a stored procedure to get a list of data with images names from `SQL DB`.

But I don't know how to use these images names and find their specific images from mapped drive by using `VB.Net`. Finally, make all images as a `excel` report.

Could anyone illustrate some samples for inserting multiple images to excel in using `VB.NET`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ReportViewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) and its image control.
Every report can be easily converted to Excel using the built-in functionality of ReportViewer.